# isset() and property_exists() not detecting property

Tags: php

While I'd like to look at an http status code for this, I don't have access to one.  So I'm looking at the response class trying to determine if a property exists and having some trouble.  This is PHP 7.

```
private function wasRateLimited(Result $result) : bool
{
    var_dump($result, isset($result->retry_after), property_exists($result, 'retry_after'));

    return isset($result->retry_after);
}
```

Here's the output:

```
/Users/myuser/mysite/app/Discord/MessageSender.php:95:
class GuzzleHttp\Command\Result#1153 (3) {
  public $global =>
  bool(false)
  public $message =>
  string(27) "You are being rate limited."
  public $retry_after =>
  int(3615)
}
/Users/myuser/mysite/app/Discord/MessageSender.php:95:
bool(false)
/Users/myuser/mysite/app/Discord/MessageSender.php:95:
bool(false)
```

Why am I not able to determine if this property exists on the response?

Comment: You are determining if it exists. It clearly doesn't. My guess is that it's retrieved by magic methods.

Comment: Can you post the code for the `Result` class?

Comment: what does `var_dump($result['retry_after']);` net you? (Trying the _ArrayAccess_ thought)

Comment: @Scuzzy That gives me what I need

Comment: Neat, `class Result implements ResultInterface` which extends `ArrayAccess`, you should be able to do `isset($result['retry_after'])` then

Comment: @Scuzzy Can you post an answer?

Comment: Done, I hope the `isset()` works properly now. (My assumptions come from working with the Amazon AWS-SDK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Guzzle `class Result implements ResultInterface` which extends `ArrayAccess` you'll have to use `$result['retry_after']` to get your property.

```
var_dump( $result['retry_after'] );

var_dump( isset( $result['retry_after'] ) );
```

- https://github.com/guzzle/command/blob/master/src/Result.php
- https://github.com/guzzle/command/blob/master/src/ResultInterface.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private function wasRateLimited(Result $result) : bool
{
    var_dump($result, isset($result->retry_after), property_exists($result, 'retry_after'));

    return ($result->retry_after) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: I end up with `Undefined property: GuzzleHttp\Command\Result::$retry_after` for responses that don't have that

Comment: @Webnet You can hide warnings by adding `ini_set('display_errors', 0);ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);error_reporting(0);` on top of your script, But this is not best solution.